# prohibit the use of my js

Tags: javascript, php, security

I need to prohibit access to my js file
except for some website.
eg I have js for special external website
so this website can load my js

but if other website wants to load this js, it should get error message

How can I do it?
please help

**Note!**

in fact, this request from external website goes to my php
and php creates js file

Can php check the host name of website which made request?

Comment: There's really no way to do this.

Comment: You can't. If a user can open your site, he can access your JS file. If he can access your JS file, he can do _anything_ he wants with it.

Comment: there's no 100% reliable way of doing this. the JS **HAS** to be downloadble for authorized users to be able to use, and there's no practical way to detect who's authorized and who isn't that can't be faked/forged/spoofed.

Comment: If you mean stopping `<script src="your-js"></script>`, then you can check the Referrer header on the server.

Comment: @Zirak Doing that will break any clients that do not pass a referrer header.

Comment: @Zirak: Which [can be spoofed](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/25795174#25795174).

Comment: @MarcB: That's not very true; you can easily protect the JS behind an authentication cookie.  However, you cannot stop copy-paste.

Comment: @Phylogenesis Which ones don't?
@Cerbrus That's why I conditioned on it coming just from the `script` tag

Comment: @SLaks: maybe so, but OP's saying it's a 3rd party script, which'd require an SSO system

Comment: We need OP (@xyz) to elaborate on his question: If he wants to stop hotlinking (`script src` and the likes), then this question is not a duplicate. If he wants to stop people from copy pasting, then it is.

Comment: @xyz, can you add the PHP code that returns the JS file to your question?

Answer (score 3):

You can't prevent users from using the file once they had access to it.

If a user can open your site, he can access your JS file.
If he can access your JS file, he can do *anything* he wants with it.

Basically, *anything* you send to the client, be it HTML, css, images or JS files can be saved, modified or re-used. There's no reliable way of preventing that other than not sending the files to unauthorized users.
As soon as a user *is* authorized, they can do whatever they want with the files that they receive.

That said, since you're using php to serve the JS file, you can probably check the referrer. No idea how, though, since I'm no php programmer.